# Extract administrative boundaries with physical borders at the coast line from OSM data

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, boundaries

I successfully downloaded the OSM data from https://www.geofabrik.de/ and converted the `.osm.pbf` file to a `.gpkg` using og2ogr. Now I want to extract administrative boundaries using DB-Manager and SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM multipolygons
WHERE admin_level = 4
```

However, I need the physical borders, which do not fall in a line with the administrative borders in coastal areas (see picture). Having a look at OSM, for example via QGIS, the information is there, but I can not figure out which key to use and how to extract them.

[image]

What would be the correct way?

Comment: Please provide example data for the seaside area, and for the land area.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I downloaded the russia-latest.osm.pbf from http://download.geofabrik.de/russia.html and I want to extract the land area separated by the admin borders. If I know the key for the land area I would clip it by myself. But I can not find a way to extract only the land area. Does this make sense?

Comment: Use the shorelines to clip the administrative polygons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong with the `admin_level` which should be `admin_level=2` instead of `admin_level=4`, check [the OSM's Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary=administrative#National).

Comment: Thank you. I've already spent a lot of time looking for the right query and I know this page. Though, for Russia 'admin_level' starts at 3. However, I need the land area - the physical border of the land area (white polygons of the countries).